# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate How I can return last push elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a problem. I have a model named `Car` which has the following structure.

```
{
  _id: '6179bd464c68a217e895703c',
  salesInfo: {
    salesDate: [
      {
        _id: '6179bd464c68a21fgff5703c',
        name: 'John'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to add multiple new sale dates inside the embedded document named `salesDate` and return these newly added sale dates as a response to the frontend something like this.

```
   data: {
    salesInfo: {
      // want to return only newly added sales date
      salesDate: [
        {
          _id: "6179bd464c1ffffgff5703c",
          name: "Doe"
        },
        {
          _id: "6179bd464cf1fgff5703c",
          name: "Tim"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am using `mongoose` `findOneAndUpdate()` method and using `$push` operator inside the update query and returning the field `salesInfo.salesDate` something like this.

```
   const salesObj = [{ name: "Doe" }, { name: "Tim" }];
    
   const response = await Car.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: "6179bd464c68a217e895703c" },
      { $push: { "salesInfo.salesDate": salesObj } },
      {
        upsert: false,
        new: true,
        fields: {
          _id: 0,
          "salesInfo.salesDate": 1,
        },
      }
    );
```

But it is returning the response with all dates, I only want newly added sale dates. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you could do it in node js , so you have `saleObj` object and when you want to return data you could replace `saleDate` with `saleObj` and return to client

Comment: @mohammadNaimi but how can I get the id of each element?

Comment: could you provide your saleObj ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi   `const salesObj = [{ name: "Doe" }, { name: "Tim" }];`

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate your data. Make a schema for the salesInfo and another for the salesDate and try to make a relation between the two schemas.
Or when you do a "findOneAndUpdate" try to use the _id of Car model not the _id of salesDate.

Answer (score 0):

read response and create your data from node js

```
   const response = await Car.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: "6179bd464c68a217e895703c" },
      { $push: { "salesInfo.salesDate": salesObj } },
      {
        upsert: false,
        new: true,
        fields: {
          _id: 1,
          "salesInfo.salesDate": 1,
        },
      }
    );
var tt = []
saleObj.forEach(item=>{
   item._id = response._id
   tt.push(item)
})
response.saleInfo.saleDate = tt
res.json(response)
```